# Having trouble extending the addition binary operation to all the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am given this:

"Assume (a1,b1)Z∼(a2,b2) and (c1,d1)Z∼(c2,d2), where each component is a natural number. Then (a1+c1,b1+d1)Z∼(a2+c2,b2+d2).

Prove dis shiznit."

The relation Z∼ is defined as (a,b) = a - b where that difference is an integer.
So (a,b)Z∼(c,d) if a+c=b+d.

The thing is, I have no idea whatsoever on how to combine 4 ordered pairs into a binary operation. Any and all help would be much appreciated!

I try adding (a1,b1) with (c1,d1), but I'm not quite sure how to prove that it is related to the sum of (a2,b2) and (c2,d2).

Comment: Write down what the given equivakeces mean, write down what the desired equivalence means, compare

Comment: So I get: (a1 + c1) + (a2 + c2) = (b1 + d1) + (b2 + d2). Does that prove what I get? I'm really confused. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$$
(a1, b1)Z\sim(a2, b2)
$$
and
$$
(c1, d1)Z\sim(c2, d2)
$$
Then
$$
a1 + a2 = b1 + b2
$$
and
$$
c1 + c2 = d1 + d2
$$
hence
$$
(a1 + c1) + (a2 + c2) = (b1 + d1) + (b2 + d2)
$$
Due to the ring properties of the natural numbers.

This means that
$$
((a1 + c1), (b1 + d1))Z\sim((a2 + c2), (b2 + d2))
$$

Comment: Ahh this makes so much more sense! I couldn't find the intuition that that long sum was equivalent to that relation! Thank you so much internet friend, I seriously appreciate it.

Comment: you're welcome. Sometimes the obvious is invisible ;-)